# PHP mysqli $conn function didnt work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to sent simple data to database, created with the xampp (port changed to 81, no password...). After inserting data to the data forms and submitting it console log sends the proper values, but the database isnt updated on the localhost and the fragment of the php: $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost:81', 'root', '', 'my_db');
$query = "INSERT into komentarze('name', 'email', 'comments') VALUES ($name, $email,     $comments)";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comments']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Shown fragment of the php code is puted into newly created p element with id="response":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {

            var name = $('#name').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var comments = $('#comments').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'submit_to_db.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'name=': name,
                        'email=': email,
                        'comments=': comments },
                //data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&comments=' + comments,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#response').remove();
                    $('#container').append('<p id="response">' + result + '</p>');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've added static values to the db and echo msg if $stmt->affected_rows or not and nothing happend ;/

Comment: Isn't the question mark used for preparing statements? `?` `VALUES(?,?,?)`

Comment: Column names, when quoted, should be enclosed by backticks instead of apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

When using mysqli, you need to replace the `$name`, `$email`, etc. with `?`. The relevant code should look like this:

```
$query = "INSERT into komentarze('name', 'email', 'comments') VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
...
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comments']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with this statement:

```
$query = "INSERT into komentarze('name', 'email', 'comments') VALUES ($name, $email,     $comments)";
```

1. Column names should be enclosed by backticks, i.e. `, instead of an apostrophes.
2. The values should be place holders instead of variables, i.e. `?, ?, ?`.

This should fix both issues:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO komentarze(`name`, `email`, `comments`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see two issues. Both relate to the binding of your query parameters.

When you bind your variable, I.e `'$_POST` you must substitute its actual value for a placeholder within your `SQL` statement. So you query would look like this:

`$query = "INSERT into komentarze('name', 'email', 'comments') VALUES (?,?,?)";`

Secondly, you would need to ensure that *each* value is bound to the query by calling subsequent calls to `bind_param` for each variable.

Comment: I have quotemarks instead variables and it didnt change nothing... I change it once again.
and binding parameters is done well ands its done with prepare($query) funcon:
  $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['name'],    $_POST['email'], $_POST['comments']);
  $stmt->execute();